# how to get value of the tinymce in jsf backing bean

Tags: jsf, tinymce

I am using tinymce editor in JSF, but I am not sure how to get this value in my Backing Bean. Please if some one has used this earlier please help me out in doing this.

```
       <script src="resources/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
   // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins :  "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

   // Theme options
   theme_advanced_buttons1 :"bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
   theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,|,bullist,numlist,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
   theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,insertfile,insertimage",
   theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
   theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
   theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
   theme_advanced_resizing : true,

   // Skin options
   skin : "o2k7",
   skin_variant : "silver",

  content_css : "css/example.css",

 });
```

```
   <ice:inputTextarea id="content" value="${bean.passage}" partialSubmit="true"/>
```

Comment: can't help you there, but Primefaces has a JSF editor component where you don't have to code any javascript. Very simple to use, see [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf).

Comment: Hi Nikita , I am really sorry, I am not sure how to accept the answer, if I got solution for my question i just add the comment saying thank u. Please let me know how to accept answer, I tried but exactly dont know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `value="${bean.passage}"` by `value="#{bean.passage}"`. The `${}` can't invoke a setter method, but the `#{}` can.

Comment: Even after changing that i have same problem. :(

Comment: JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),
"tinyMCE.get('content').getContent();"); I tried with this also but the sad part its not working if textarea is within panel tab.

Answer (score 1):

**Connect the tinyMCE to your jsf component by selector**

in the following example you load an own javascript file "loadhtmleditor.js" that contains the function "loadMyEditor()". This function is called in *body onload*.
In this javascript function you connect the tinyMCE to your jsf component by *selector* not by *mode*. In the selector argument you write the html-id of the component to be connected. Be aware that in this argument the ':' separators in the html-ids generated by jsf must be masked with two backslashes! In this example: selector : "#myForm\\:myHtmlText"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <script src="resources/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="resources/loadhtmleditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body onload="loadMyEditor();">
    <h:form id="myForm">
        <h:inputTextarea id="myHtmlText" value="#{bean.htmlText}">
        </h:inputTextarea>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

loadhtmleditor.js:

```
function loadMyEditor()
{
    tinyMCE.init({
           // General options
            selector : "#myForm\\:myHtmlText",
            theme : "advanced",
            plugins :  "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
           // Theme options
           theme_advanced_buttons1 :"bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
           theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,|,bullist,numlist,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
           theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,insertfile,insertimage",
           theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
           theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
           theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
           theme_advanced_resizing : true,
           // Skin options
           skin : "o2k7",
           skin_variant : "silver",
          content_css : "css/example.css",
         });
}
```

This should be sufficient to have binded your jsf bean to the tinyMCE!

**Addition:**
If you want to **react by ajax** when the user changes the html content you can extend the creation of the tinyMCE editor like this:

loadhtmleditor.js:

```
function loadMyEditor()
{
    tinyMCE.init({
           // General options
            selector : "#myForm\\:myHtmlText",
            theme : "advanced",
            plugins :  "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
           // Theme options
           theme_advanced_buttons1 :"bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
           theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,|,bullist,numlist,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
           theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,insertfile,insertimage",
           theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
           theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
           theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
           theme_advanced_resizing : true,
           // Skin options
           skin : "o2k7",
           skin_variant : "silver",

           init_instance_callback: function (editor)
           {
               editor.on('Change', function(e){myFunctionEditorChanged(editor);});
               editor.on('Paste', function(e){myFunctionEditorPasted(editor);});
           },
           content_css : "css/example.css"
         });
}


function myFunctionEditorChanged(editor)
{
    tinyMCE.triggerSave(); // to be shure, that the changed content is in your jsf-component...
    // do something to trigger an ajax request handeling the changed html content. 
}


function myFunctionEditorPasted(editor)
{
    tinyMCE.triggerSave(); // to be shure, that the changed content is in your jsf-component...
    // do something to trigger an ajax request handeling the changed html content. 
}
```

In this way you can react to all changes the user entered to the html editor by keybord or by pasting content. I didn't find a way to get informed, when the user changes the html content by the menu of tinyMCE. ( for example when the user changes some words to be bold...)